# Aggregation over another aggregation

Tags: elasticsearch

I am using date histogram aggregation on documents in my Elasticsearch index.

This is my query:

```
GET _search
{  
"aggs":{
    "per_four_hours":{
        "date_histogram":{
            "field":"ad_inTime",
            "interval":"4h",
            "extended_bounds":{
                "min":1461789171000,
                "max":1476078286000
            },
            "time_zone":"Asia/Kolkata"
        }
    }
}
}
```

As expected I am getting aggregations with an interval of 4 hours.

Now I want to aggregate on the buckets received.I want to add the "doc_count" of every 6th bucket.Is there any way to do it?

If not,is there some other way to apply date histogram using scripts to get aggregation based on 4 hours?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Why do you need 4h buckets and afterward a sum for every 6th bucket?

Comment: I want to display the number of events based on 4 hour interval in a day.For example,given a start date and end date I want to display what is the trend of events during different times of day(in intervals of 4 hours).So the sum of every 6th bucket gives me count of events in that 4 hour interval.

Comment: I still don't understand. Trend of events is relevant for all the buckets, not only the 6th bucket...

Comment: One day has 24 hours.If you divide it into intervals of 4 hours,we get 6 intervals.Lets say my "start_date" is 1 Jan and "end_date" is 3rd Jan.The results that I am getting are 6 buckets for 1st Jan,6 buckets for 2nd Jan,6 buckets for 3rd Jan.I want to add the doc_count of first bucket of each day,then second bucket of each day and so on till the 6th bucket.